# Gradle move build folder to /tmp

Tags: gradle, build, tmpfs

I wonder how is it possible to move build folder to somewhere, like `/tmp`.

In my case `/tmp` folder is tmpfs, home folder is encrypted. I see no reason why not to speedup build process and decrease load of hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be changed with [`setBuildDir`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#setBuildDir(java.lang.Object)) method. This method takes a path argument.

```
buildDir = '/path/to/dir`
```

Comment: ```project.buildDir = '/tmp/folder'``` works for me, thanks! Average build time was: 46s, now 34s!